# Microsoft Word 2016 VBA issues with LinkToPrevious

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, footer, sections

We have developed some Microsoft Word tools in VBA that allow a user to add sections to a document with options for A3 and A4 page size and portrait and landscape orientation. We use a form to present the user with radio buttons where (the user) can select new section page size and orientation. The VBA code adds a new section then turns off the header and footer ‘same as previous’ setting, sets margins and adds specific autotexts on headers and footers to control layout of the header and footer, i.e depending on the radio button selected.  The document we are experiencing issues with – also has odd and even pages.  But also fails in a document without odd and even page layout.

We have used this piece of code for many years on Word 2010 without problem but we are now experiencing inconsistent issues on Word 2016 and in the following part of code. i.e. the code randomly does not turn off ‘same as previous’  even though the code is specifically setting ‘Link to Previous’ to false. Below is a part of the code we used without issues on Word 2010 and fail now:

```
        With NewSection
            .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Footers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).LinkToPrevious = False
        End With
```

Are there known issues with what we are trying to do above? Why the ‘Link to Previous’ may not be working consistently.

Another issue that can be related to above one, is that on Word 2016 we get below message even when a previous section exists:
[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaqJm.png)

It fails randomly on one of the above lines of code, for example:
[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8J6C.png)

Is the second issue is related to the first?

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt: Thank you far the warning. I added links to the screenshots now.

Comment: I am not aware of anything specific to Wd2016 that should cause this behaviour. I certainly haven’t seen this behaviour in O365. From the screenshots it looks as though `NewSection` may not be pointing to the section you intended, but as you have only included a short piece of your code it is not possible to debug. If this is only occurring on certain documents it is possible that it is related to document corruption.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt: _NewSection_ is created using below statement:
`NewSection = ActiveDocument.Sections.Add(rng)`
and _rng_: 
`Set rng=Selection.Range`.
This is occurring (random) even on new created documents so not only on a certain document.

Comment: If it is entirely random it is going to be difficult to debug. Possibilities include: corrupt document; corrupt template; corrupt Normal.dotm.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt: I found the piece of code (see below) that causes this. After setting same as previous my code set margins, orientation and page size, then insert autotext on footer and use this code to send image to back:  `.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack`  `.Footers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack`
First time when code run same as previous work OK because above code runs after but is occurring when run second time on same Word session. If I save doc and close Word then on opening again work well first time too.

Comment: I encounter the same issue in my Word Add-in (vb.net). The error arrives randomly in a routine, which inserts a section break and unlinks the header and the footer. The error message is the same ("no previous section found"). - I tried a lot of workarounds, e.g. counting the sections (Result: 2), moving the selection object to the 2nd section to provoke that Word updates the internal information, but stubbornly Word decides sometimes that there is only one section.